# MvcSiteMapProvider get wrong Id parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mvcsitemapprovider

I using MvcSiteMapProvider to create treeview navigator in Asp.net MVC 4

I have 2 link like:

~/Home/Article/{id} and 
~/Home/Gallery/{id}

my Treeview like: Home -> Article -> Gallery

And I used dynamic code on Controller

```
    [MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Article", ParentKey = "Home", Key="Article", PreservedRouteParameters="id")]
    public ActionResult Article(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.Id = id; 
        return View();
    }
    [MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Gallery", Key="Gallery" ParentKey = "Article", PreservedRouteParameters="id")]
    public ActionResult Gallery(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.id = id;
        return View();
    }
```

So it run success, but Problem is when i have 
~/Home/Article/123 and I go to ~/Home/Gallery/456

Next I click on treeview to go back Article, it set wrong ID parameter in article, It get Gallery's id set for Article's Id look like: ~/Home/Article/456.

Anyone have solver?. Sorry about my english, it bad.

Comment: This bug has been fixed in 4.0.5. There was a path through the logic that caused matches to happen on invalid nodes that has been addressed.

Answer (score 0):

You could explicitly set the name of the parameter.

Eg.

```
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Article", ParentKey = "Home", Key="Article", PreservedRouteParameters="ArticleId")]
public ActionResult Article(int ArticleId)
{
    ViewBag.Id = ArticleId; 
    return View();
}

[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Gallery", Key="Gallery" ParentKey = "Article", PreservedRouteParameters="GalleryId")]
public ActionResult Gallery(int GalleryId)
{
    ViewBag.id = GalleryId;
    return View();
}
```

Then:

`/Home/Article/123`

`/Home/Gallery?GalleryId=456&ArticleId=123`

Comment: yup, i see, but problem if i have many parameter like /Home/Article/{id}?name=""&email="" and /Home/Gallery/{Galleryid}?name=""&email="". so will i change all parameter name? /Home/Gallery/{Galleryid}?GalleryName=""&Galleryemail="". Right, it not friendly. Thanks You so much for your reponse